# JUnit test keeps getting null point exceptions

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create JUnit tests for my application, but I keep getting `NullPointerException`.
My method is to establish a keybased auth SFTP connection, and all those `sftp???` and `als???` strings are all taken from my another class where I grab values from `application.properties` via `@Value`.

This is the class and method I am trying to test.

```
import static mypackage.static.alsFunctionId;
// Some more static imports here...

@Component
public class SftpConnection {

    private Logging logger;
    @Autowired
    public SftpConnection(Logging logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public Session MakeConnectionByKey () {

        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = null;

            jsch.addIdentity(sftpPrivateKeyPath);
            session = jsch.getSession(sftpUsername, sftpHostname, sftpPort);

            session.setConfig(
                    "StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"
                    );

            session.setConfig(
                    "PreferredAuthentications", 
                    "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");

            session.connect();

            if(session.isConnected()) {
                return session;
            } else {
                System.out.println("NOT Connected!");
            }

        } catch (JSchException e) {
            logger.WriteLog(alsPlatform, "INFO", alsProjectCode, alsFunctionId, alsTransactionId, alsOperationId, "SFTP_CONNECTION", e.getClass().getCanonicalName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            //System.err.println(e);
            //return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the test method.

```
private Session session;
private SftpConnection sftpConnection;
private Logging logger;

@Before
void setUp() throws Exception {
    logger = new Logging();
    sftpConnection = new SftpConnection(logger);
    session = null; 
}

@Test
public void shouldGetSession() throws JSchException {
    session = sftpConnection.MakeConnectionByKey2();
    assertThat(session.isConnected()).isTrue();
}
```

Does anyone have idea where the `NullPointerException` comes from? I tried to replace all those string variables with actual String values but still no luck.

Comment: session may be null, can you post the console output

Comment: The exception stack trace will tell you which line of which class the exception occurs on.  From that, you should be able to work out which variable is unexpectedly null.  That information should help you solve the problem.  But from what you've shown here, there's not enough information to tell you what's going on.

Comment: In test cases you are calling MakeConnectionByKey2() method while in above code MakeConnectionByKey() been defined. NPE may come from any place, In my sense above method (MakeConnectionByKey()) is **returning null** if **session is not connected**. While test case is looking **session.isConnected()** which is ending up with Null Pointer Exception for the reason session is null.

Comment: Thank you guys. from Failure Trace(I'm using STS) I see it is reporting `session = sftpConnection.MakeConnectionByKey();` is getting a null pointer, but I can't be sure what makes this happen.
@ThilinaRubasingha I am not seeing anything on console at all
@SwaritAgarwal Yes, that is because I tried to isolate those import static string variables and I created `MakeConnectionByKey2()` to test. But you are right, both don't work.

Comment: MakeConnectionByKey () method you only catch the JSchException. So if any other exception occurs, it will not be displayed in the console output. Try to adding another catch block and catch  (Exception e) main class. That will display the exception trace. According to the current implementation, when exception happen other than JSchException, MakeConnectionByKey () returning null session.

Comment: @ThilinaRubasingha Thanks for comment. However, actually `MakeConnectionByKey()` works fine if I test and run the code manually on my own.